# need to revert a commit on git remote

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

me and my partner are working on a project.
we have a release branch. From this we checked out our feature branch.

TO work on parallel we created 2 more branches from the feature branch. one for me and the other for y partner.

The issue:
By mistake I have committed the changes of my private branch and merged it to feature branch without testing. I want to undo my changes on the feature branch? is it possible?

Solutions tried:
i tried "git reset HEAD~1" , but it is not reflecting on the bitbucket gui.

Comment: Go to branch you want to "repair", run `git reset --hard {commit}` then `git push --force`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo the most recent commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git)

Comment: Have you solved the problem by using `git push -f` after the command `git reset --hard HEAD~1`?

Comment: If your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer. And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing the reset, see if you are at right commit using `git log`. Then just force push it using `git push -u origin master -f`

Comment: `-u origin master` is unnecessary if the tracking branch is already set, which is likely.